# How can I fix a cabinet to plasterboard with brick wall behind?

Tags: drywall

I aim to fit a (fairly heavy) kitchen wall cabinet to a plasterboard wall. Behind the plasterboard there does not appear to be any studs. So I guess the plasterboard (what I would call drywall - plasterboard with no studs) has been glued to the brick exterior wall which lies behind the plasterboard. The cabinet once fitted will be laden with lots of heavy pans etc.

Can the plasterboard be drilled through and into the brick wall behind it? What type of plugs / fastening would be recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend these lag shields

[image]
 but the info in this [link](http://www.tmcinc.org/CATALOG%20PDFS/Y_ANCHORS-WEB.pdf) can help you decide. You could probably go with simple lead sleeves but without knowing the condition of your brick or the exact weight of the load you'll be supporting lag shields are a safer bet. As far as going through the plasterboard goes, it's not any different than attaching something to studs through drywall, you just need to make sure you're drywall is compressed between the cabinet back and the supporting wall. If there is a void between the two it will collapse when you tighten down your anchors or worse, when you put weight in your cabinet.

Comment: The gap between the board and the wall is fairly large  - 40mm (over 1 1/2 inches). I'm now thinking of cutting the board to snugly fit a batten which will screw into the wall.

Comment: @suspectus, use spray foam to seal the whole in the plaster board, so you don't get any drafts from it.

Comment: If the drywall is an 1 1/2" off the brick I'd suspect it's furred out with some 2x2's or 2x4's laid flat on 16 or 24" centers. I mean the drywall has to be attached to something  right? If you can locate the furring strips it might be best to just mount your cabinet to them. You'll probably have to drill holes as the brick may fool your stud finder.

Comment: From the front face of the board to the wall is just over 1 1/2" (40mm). From the inside face I guess the gap is 28mm (1 1/8"). Tapping the wall there appears to be nothing solid between the end of the wall and a window (3ft 3"). Will drill hole(s) later thanks.